# operator keyword in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I'm reading thinking in C++. There is a code fragment that I don't understand. 
Can anyone help me explain it?

```
class GameBoard {
public:
  GameBoard() { cout << "GameBoard()\n"; }
  GameBoard(const GameBoard&) { 
    cout << "GameBoard(const GameBoard&)\n"; 
  }
  GameBoard& operator=(const GameBoard&) {
    cout << "GameBoard::operator=()\n";
    return *this;
  }
  ~GameBoard() { cout << "~GameBoard()\n"; }
};

class Game {
  GameBoard gb; // Composition
public:
  // Default GameBoard constructor called:
  Game() { cout << "Game()\n"; }
  // You must explicitly call the GameBoard
  // copy-constructor or the default constructor
  // is automatically called instead:
  Game(const Game& g) : gb(g.gb) { 
    cout << "Game(const Game&)\n"; 
  }
  Game(int) { cout << "Game(int)\n"; }
  Game& operator=(const Game& g) {
    // You must explicitly call the GameBoard
    // assignment operator or no assignment at 
    // all happens for gb!
    gb = g.gb;
    cout << "Game::operator=()\n";
    return *this;
  }
  class Other {}; // Nested class
  // Automatic type conversion:
  operator Other() const {
    cout << "Game::operator Other()\n";
    return Other();
  }
  ~Game() { cout << "~Game()\n"; }
};
```

In the above code fragment, I don't understand:

```
  operator Other() const {
    cout << "Game::operator Other()\n";
    return Other();
  }
```

I guess this function define an operator "`Other()`". What doe it mean for returning `Other()`?
If `Other()` means an object of class Other, the return type of operator "`Other()`" is not a type of class `Other`.

Comment: Technically, It is a conversion operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a **conversion** operator (**NOT** a cast operator). Whenever your code calls for a **conversion** to `Other` the operator will be used. There are two ways your code can call for a conversion. An **implicit** conversion occurs in situations like this:

```
Game g;
Game::Other o(g); // **implicit conversion** of g to Game::Other
```

An **explicit conversion** occurs when you write a **cast** in your code:

```
Game g;
Game::Other o(static_cast<Game::Other>(g)); // **explicit conversion**
    // of g to Game::Other
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a cast operator.

When you'd write `(Other)game;` (i.e. you cast a game to `Other`).

It will be called.

Answer (score 0):

This is a C++ casting operator. It defines what happens if an object will be casted to class Other.

Comment: it's a conversion operator!